# devise first login with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

How can I determine on my custom session controller that the user is the first time login, I want to be able to create a session and to redirect to `welcome#index` if its the first time else it would be redirected to `root_url`.

The code that I have is has follow

```
class MysessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)    
  end
  protected
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    "http://google.com"

  end 
end
```

I know I need to custom `after_sign_up_path_for(resource)` to what I want but I cant find how to determine if the user has sign in before or not with devise

Comment: `after_sign_up_path_for` determines what page the user is directed to after signing up, which will obviously be their first time logging in (since it is directly after signing up).

Comment: So the code that i have works?

Comment: You might have to move your `after_sign_up_path_for` to a custom registrations controller (instead of sessions). Or even move it to ApplicationController.

Comment: The problem i have is that i am using the confirmable module, so what i am thinking is to have my session with the two method but i dont think calling both of them is great any solution

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you should be able to do this with `:sign_in_count` column. if this is 0 it means user has not sign in before

So as an example

```
redirect_to ((current_user.sign_in_count == 0) ? path1 : path2 )
```