# Devise Redirect First Login

Tags: redirect, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

We are trying to route a new user to fill out a Fact Sheet on their first login and then land on their Dashboard the rest of the time.

Going on this post here: 
[devise first login with rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14743396/devise-first-login-with-rails)

We added this to our application controller:

```
def 
after_sign_in_path_for(user) 
redirect_to ((current_user.sign_in_count == 0) ? new_fact_sheet_path : dashboard_index_path )
end
```

But we get this error:

"AbstractController::DoubleRenderError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create
Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".

We thought we were overriding Devise default routing with a redirect in the application controller?

Solution: 
This ended up being a two-part solution as noted in comments below. Code that worked:

```
def 
after_sign_in_path_for(user) 
((current_user.sign_in_count == 1) ? new_fact_sheet_path : dashboard_index_path )
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the reason for your DoubleRenderError is because `after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)` should just return the path which is later used to redirect by devise.  However, you're calling `redirect_to` within your overridden `after_sign_in_path_for()`, so it is being redirected twice.  Just drop the `redirect_to` and simply return the appropriate path.

Comment: Thank you!  That in combination with the information from the answer below did the trick. Removing the redirect_to got rid of our error but didn't get us to the right page. We had do make the adjustment as noted below to get the right behavior out of Devise.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be on DeviseSessionController,
read this: [Devise After first login redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21572664/devise-after-first-login-redirect)

the people used the same thing and it works.

Comment: Thank you! That led us to the second issue once we have solved our error, we needed to change the sign_in_count == 1.