# Devise After first login redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

Normally `after_sign_up_path` would work but now that i have `confirmations`, this goes to the trash.

I'm searching for a way to redirect a user on his `FIRST SIGN IN`, meaning that

- sign_in_count == 0
- last_sign_in == nil

so i added to my `applications_controller.rb`

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(user)
  if current_user.sign_in_count == 0
    welcome_path
  end
end
```

but *of course* this didn't work. What am i missing ?

Comment: I should be work with user who is going to login first but not for other user who already log in previously.
You should give else block for if.

Comment: That is the think, it doesn't work...

Comment: I think after signin it will become 1 not 0

Comment: Yeah we figured it out :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After testing, we found Devise sets the value of `sign_in_count` immediately after login, meaning that it's never going to be `0`, it's going to be `1` for a first-time login:

```
#config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: "sessions" }

#app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb
class SessionController < Devise::DeviseController

    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
        if resource.sign_in_count == 1
           welcome_path
        else
           root_path
        end
    end

end
```

Comment: can it be => class Devise::SessionsController < DeviseController ? cause what you wrote throws me an error..

Comment: I think it should be this: `Class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController`

Comment: I lifted the code from an older version of Devise (hence why I think it threw an error)

Comment: lol okay - let me know if it works. I hope so, but I feel it may need a reference to self or something

Comment: nice - let me check to see if I can add the required reference (I mistook for a class method)

Comment: Updated with reference

Comment: :( seems that it isn't so simple, or i'm missing something big... Not Working

Comment: What errors are you getting back? Also check your DB to see if the sign_in_count is indeed 0

Comment: After confirmation entries are 0 and nil (Perfect). error -> http://i.imgur.com/DN4QaVV.png

Comment: You need to include `resource.sign_in_count`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46822/discussion-between-the-mini-john-and-rich-peck)

Comment: Missing S in SessionsController, too small error to submit an edit for it.

Comment: @RichardPeck what about sign up redirect? would this work as well

Answer (score 0):

User "user" instead of current_user.

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(user)
  if user.sign_in_count == 0
    welcome_path
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried that, but it redirects me to current_user instead of welcome_path

Answer (score 0):

You passed 'user' as a variable  then you have to use that one. And give else block also because you are overriding this method, then what about the other already logged in user.

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(user)
  if current_user.sign_in_count == 0
    welcome_path
  else
    #root_path
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In ApplicationController (without devise sessions controller), using Ruby 2.5.1 and RoR 5.1.6

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(user)
  if user.sign_in_count == 1
    first_test_path #see note below
  else
    second_test_path
  end
end
```

I am directing users to the `edit_user_path` on first login - replacing `first_test_path` - with:

```
edit_user_path(current_user)
```